# iOS 3ds file some time render incorrect ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality, vuforia, 3ds

I'm used voufria with objective c  to display objects on targets  .... but I am having a strange problem - sometimes show incorrect objects or small(I do not know how to define the scale) - and if you delete the application and download it again is larger than the previous object, but do not show the colors of the object
Thanks

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. It might help if you include small bits of code to show what you are doing and screenshots to show the problems and the behaviour you want.

Comment: sorry , iam using this code with voufria/render https://github.com/DrNeuroSurg/REVu/tree/master/REVU_IOS     the problem is with this line   model1->ScaleUniformTo(0.4); how to determine scale 0.4 or 0.2

Comment: You should edit your question and include the relevant code directly in the question, not link to it. Also you've linked to the whole repository, not the specific file you're talking about.